# Adding commit message to top of .c/.h files in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am currently looking for a way to add the commit message to the top of my .c/.h files that are modified when I commit them into the repo. In CSRCS it looked like this at the top of the file

- CSRCS Log
- $Log$
- Revision 1.17  2022-05-12 11:59:32-07  username
- Updated R01.00.00 for bug fixes (This is the commit message fyi)

Any idea how to add this into SVN? Thanks

Have not found anything relevant yet to help.